# Apache Solr - facet for empty search in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, solr

I want to have a facet show up on an empty search, but I'm unable to figure out how to do this.

For example, if I am going to www.domain.com/tech, it will only show the facets that actually have values relating to tech. I don't want that, I want all facets to show, no matter if there's 0 entries or 1000 entries.

How do I make even empty facets show?

Comment: Did you look into http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters for faceting?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [apachesolr](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module? If so go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » Apache Solr search » Pages/Blocks tab.

Under "Advanced Search Page Options" go to the "Behavior On Empty Search" section.

Choose the "Show enabled facets" option that works for you.